# my if/else if statment makes me input multiple times before running

Tags: c#

So when I run the code I can press 1 and that runs fine but when I try entering 2 or 3 then the computer makes me enter 2 or 3 multiple times before running that line of code.

I don't know what the problem with this is. 
I'm new so if there is a better way to run something like this instead of if statements please let me know.

```
using System;


namespace PracticeScript
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int playerHp = 100;
            int enemyHp = 100;
            int playerD = rnd.Next(10, 15);
            int enemyD = rnd.Next(10, 15);
            int potion = 25;


            Console.Write("Get Ready! It's time to battle! ");
            Console.WriteLine("You stare into the eyes of the ugly goblin and are ready to slay it with your sword \n");

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" what will you do now?");
                Console.WriteLine("\n 1. Attack    2. Defend    3. Use potion");

                if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")
                {
                    enemyHp -= playerD;
                    Console.WriteLine("you swung your sword and struck the goblin in the body leaving it " + enemyHp + "HP left over");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You prepaired your sheild for the incoming attack");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "3")
                {
                    playerHp += potion;
                    Console.WriteLine("You chugged down the potion as quick as you could and now have " + playerHp + " left!" );
                }


                Console.WriteLine("\nEnemy Turn!");
                playerHp -= enemyD;
                Console.WriteLine("The goblin struck you with his mace and left you with " + playerHp + "HP left!");


            } while (playerHp > 0 || enemyHp > 0);
```

Comment: You need to store the result of `Console.ReadLine` before testing its value

Comment: I always new "Defend" was a placebo choice! ;)

Comment: damn goblins...

Comment: Remember to check for invalid inputs, I gave you an idea in my answer ^^

Comment: @JNevill if you drink potions you can fight forever!

Comment: `int potion = 2147483647;` In all seriousness, this is a great test/sample program. My first "game" was "Guess a number between 1 and 1000" on my Ti-83 (omg they still sell those). Fun to play exactly twice. My 11 year old son just wrote the same game on a Ti-81 he needed for class. So proud.

Comment: @JNevill I'm not surprised Ti-83s are still on the market but a pupil using a Ti-81 nowadays... 8-|

Comment: @vc74 Well.. he's 11 and the requirement was "scientific calculator" so instead of the 2 dollar scientific calculator at the walmart, we stumbled upon a 3 dollar TI-81 at an estate sale. Now the little booger is writing `goto` statements like a pro ;)

Comment: @JNevill Teach him out to code without those before it's too late ;)

Comment: well thanks for the answer i've been busy but finally go back on this and all the input has been amazingly helpful

Answer (score 4):

You need to store the result of Console.ReadLine before testing its value:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();

if (line == "1")
{
    enemyHp -= playerD;
    Console.WriteLine("you swung your sword and struck the goblin in the body leaving it " + enemyHp + "HP left over");
}
else if (line == "2")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You prepaired your sheild for the incoming attack");
}
else if (line == "3")
{
    playerHp += potion;
    Console.WriteLine("You chugged down the potion as quick as you could and now have " + playerHp + " left!" );
}
```

Otherwise your program will call `Console.ReadLine` 3 times and prompt the user 3 times in the worst case.

Comment: Even if the `if else` isn't wrong, I think that you should suggest to use the `switch` statement which is the one made for these cases

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I actually thought about it but EJoshuaS's reply nicely fills the gap

Answer (score 2):

`Console.ReadLine()` will prompt for input every time you call it.

You can use a `switch` statement instead to ask for input once and compare it against every value you want to handle:

```
switch (Console.ReadLine())
 {
    case "1":
       // ...
       break;

    case "2":
       // ...
       break;
   // Add rest of cases here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are evaluating each `Console.Readline()` each time the user enters a value.  So, user enter `2`, `if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")` evaluates to `false`.  Enters 2 again, `else if (Console.ReadLine() == "2")` evaluates to `true`.  As others have stated, use `Console.ReadLine()` once per loop, store the value, and check it in your `if` statements:

```
string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
if(userinput == "1")
    // do stuff
else if(userinput == "2")
    // do other stuff
//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a `switch`

The problem was the fact that you repeated 3 time `Console.ReadLine()` instead of storing and using its value!

Plus, I added a check of the user input, you didn't think about the possibility to have an **invalid input**!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int playerHp = 100;
        int enemyHp = 100;
        int playerD = rnd.Next(10, 15);
        int enemyD = rnd.Next(10, 15);
        int potion = 25;


        Console.Write("Get Ready! It's time to battle! ");
        Console.WriteLine("You stare into the eyes of the ugly goblin and are ready to slay it with your sword \n");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" what will you do now?");
            Console.WriteLine("\n 1. Attack    2. Defend    3. Use potion");


            bool isInputValid = false;
            while (isInputValid == false)
            {
                isInputValid = true;
                switch (Console.ReadLine())
                {
                    case "1":
                        enemyHp -= playerD;
                        Console.WriteLine("you swung your sword and struck the goblin in the body leaving it " + enemyHp + "HP left over");
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        Console.WriteLine("You prepaired your sheild for the incoming attack");
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        playerHp += potion;
                        Console.WriteLine("You chugged down the potion as quick as you could and now have " + playerHp + " left!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please choose a listed action!");
                        isInputValid = false;
                        break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnemy Turn!");
            playerHp -= enemyD;
            Console.WriteLine("The goblin struck you with his mace and left you with " + playerHp + "HP left!");


        } while (playerHp > 0 || enemyHp > 0);
    }
}
```